# Conditions for dual of nonplanar graph to have no odd length cycles

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $\gamma$ be a graph (not necessarily simple) of genus $g$. Are there any conditions that I can impose on $\gamma$ such that the dual of $\gamma$ has no cycles of odd length? If not, what if we allow the assumption of simplicity?